# How to Display a file's text in python tkinter text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

folks, I'm trying to display a text file with python on GUI using python(version - 3.5) tkinter, however I'm finding some difficulties while displaying the text from the file in text widget of tkinter. can someone guide me how to do it.

**MY CODE:**

```
configfile = Text(f3, wrap=WORD, width=45, height= 20)
filename='/etc/hosts'
file = open(filename,'r')
f = file.readlines()
configfile.insert(INSERT,[print(i) for i in f])
configfile.pack(fill="none", expand=TRUE)
```

**Note:** I'm just using print for now. I want to display it in the text widget instead of printing in cli. Also I've omitted posting the full source code in order to avoid confusions since I'm bit new to tkinter and python.

someone please guide me how. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What does `set()` have to do with inserting text into a Text widget? What is wrong with simply inserting the text string into Text with `.insert(INSERT, yourtext)`?

Comment: I'm trying to insert text which I read from my file '/etc/hosts'

Comment: It would help if you attempt to address my previous concerns. I understand what you try to do, I do not understand why you need `set` and why you do not simply insert the text with `.insert`.

Comment: I just mentioned I know set wouldn't work here. so I asked an alternate method, I got it now by using @Bryan Oakley method

Comment: The point is that `set` is completely irrelevant here. Mentioning an irrelevant detail in your question makes it hard to understand.

Comment: ok I got it, will edit it right away. sure would correct next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do. Just read the file and insert the contents.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    configfile.insert(INSERT, f.read())
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks @Bryan Oakley
I think I've complicated things :-) thanks for pointing me out. Its working as i expected